# Firebase GeoFire setlocation not working in service

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

Okay so i have the following code and its working fine, but when I destroy the activity then it stop working.

```java
DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("REFERENCE");
                    GeoFire mGeoFire = new GeoFire(ref2);
                    mGeoFire.setLocation(
                            "KEY",
                            new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),new
                                    GeoFire.CompletionListener(){
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                                            //Do some stuff if you want to
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged - in Firebase onComplete: "+error );

                                        }
                                    });
```

Everything is working fine except when application is killed.

**EDIT** I have tried service as separate process as well but still no luck.

Comment: App didn't crash at all, I tried try catch too, it never goes to onComplete!

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I would be worried about database structure if it wasn't working at all, It works if i am inside the activity the service updates the value but as soon as i exit the activity it stops working!